# What is the info displayed by radare2's afl?

Tags: tools, radare2

I can't figure out what `afl` actually outputs. The docs are surprisingly uninformative.

So, I've got address on the first column and symbol on the last. **What is on the 2nd, 3rd and 4th columns?**

**Example:**

```
:> afl
0x08048000   29 988  -> 937  segment.LOAD0
0x080483dc    3 35           func_5
0x08048410    1 6            sym.imp.fgets
0x08048420    1 6            sym.imp.fclose
0x08048430    1 6            sym.imp.fwrite
0x08048440    1 6            sym.imp.puts
0x08048450    1 6            loc.imp.__gmon_start
0x08048460    1 6            sym.imp.exit
0x08048470    1 6            sym.imp.__libc_start_main
0x08048480    1 6            sym.imp.fopen
0x08048490    1 6            sym.imp.fileno
0x080484a0    1 6            sym.imp.ptrace
0x080484b0    1 33           entry0
0x080484e0    1 4            func_3
0x080484f0    4 42           func_4
0x08048642    4 51           func_1
0x08048675   10 83           func_2
0x080486c8    4 194          main
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, I'll answer your question straightly:

- 2nd column: The number of [basic blocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_block) in the function
- 3rd column: The size of the function (in bytes)
- 4th column: The function's name

You might have used "4th" to spot the number that comes after the "->". If this is the case, where there is a "->" the left number is the *range* of the function where on the right you can find the *size* of the function. It happens only when the range and the size are different.

---

But now for a more generic approach. As you noticed, some commands of radare2 would not show you the column headers of the table, just as your example with the `afl` command. So what can you do to show this information?

### Use the JSON output

Simply, use the JSON representation of the output. Most of radare2's informative commands can be appended with a j to format the output as JSON. Add ~{} to format the output with JSON indention for readability:

So for example:

```
[0x00400430]> aflj~{}                   
[                                       
  {                                     
    "offset": 4195272,                  
    "name": "sym._init",                
    "size": 26,                         
    "realsz": 26,                       
    "cc": 2,                            
    "cost": 12,                         
    "nbbs": 3,                          
    "edges": 3,                         
    "ebbs": 1,                          
    "calltype": "amd64",                
    "type": "sym",                      
    "minbound": "4195272",              
    "maxbound": "4195298",              
    "range": "26",                      
    "diff": "NEW",    
    ...
    ...
```

As you can see, radare presents us with a simple JSON output that contains the headers (keys) for each value. You can easily understand what each column is, using the header name which is corresponding to the output without `j`.

### Use a more verbose command

An alternative for `afl` is `afll`. It will list the functions of the binary in a verbose mode and in an easy to understand table:

```
[0x00400430]> afll
address            size  nbbs edges    cc cost          min bound range max bound          calls locals args xref frame name
================== ==== ===== ===== ===== ==== ================== ===== ================== ===== ====== ==== ==== ===== ====
0x004003c8   26     3     3     2   12 0x004003c8    26 0x004003e2     1    0      0    1     8 sym._init
0x00400400    6     1     0     1    3 0x00400400     6 0x00400406     0    0      0    1     0 sym.imp.puts
0x00400410    6     1     0     1    3 0x00400410     6 0x00400416     0    0      0    1     0 sym.imp.__libc_start_main
0x00400420    6     1     0     1    3 0x00400420     6 0x00400426     0    0      0    1     0 sub.__gmon_start_420
0x00400430   41     1     0     1   15 0x00400430    41 0x00400459     1    0      0    0     8 entry0
0x00400460   41     4     4     2   20 0x00400460    50 0x00400492     0    0      0    1     8 sym.deregister_tm_clones
0x004004a0   53     3     2    -1   20 0x004004a0    53 0x004004d5     0    0      0    2     8 sym.register_tm_clones
0x004004e0   28     3     3     2   14 0x004004e0    28 0x004004fc     1    0      0    0     0 sym.__do_global_dtors_aux
0x00400500   35     4     6     4   19 0x00400500    38 0x00400526     0    0      0    0     8 entry1.init
0x00400526   21     1     0     1   12 0x00400526    21 0x0040053b     1    0      0    1     8 sym.main
0x00400540  101     4     5     3   49 0x00400540   101 0x004005a5     1    0      0    1    56 sym.__libc_csu_init
0x004005b0    2     1     0     1    3 0x004005b0     2 0x004005b2     0    0      0    1     0 sym.__libc_csu_fini
0x004005b4    9     1     0     1    5 0x004005b4     9 0x004005bd     0    0      0    0     8 sym._fini
```

`afll` listed the functions but this time it showed you the columns' header name.

Comment: Very informative, thanks. Could you please clarify what the line coloring means on afll?

Comment: `afll`.  What a beauty!